# How to determine a week given start day and end day?

Tags: string, date, if-statement, google-sheets

I would like to write a function in Google Spreadsheets which simply gives me the week A given Start day B and End Day C.

```
                A          B           C

               201507   09/02/2015  15/02/2015
               201508   16/02/2015  22/02/2015
               201509   23/02/2015  01/03/2015
               201510   02/03/2015  08/03/2015
               201511   09/03/2015  15/03/2015
               201512   16/03/2015  22/03/2015
               201513   23/03/2015  29/03/2015
               201514   30/03/2015  05/04/2015
               201515   06/04/2015  12/04/2015
               201516   13/04/2015  19/04/2015
```

I though about implementing a mod function `mod(x,7)=0` which restarts the week after 7 days but that was somehow difficult to implement, at least for me.

Comment: So... what have you tried so far?

Comment: @HiThere can I ask for a little clarification on your question? How does column A play a role in what you wish? What values does it hold? It might be useful to create a column D and put the results you expect in there.

Comment: Column A is the wished result in that particular format. Its just the week. In my spreadsheet I just have B and C and would like to generate a corresponding week as a function of B and C in order to automatically update the table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @Munkey's solution, but shorter:

```
=year(B1)&text(weeknum(B1),"00")
```

Assumes `09/02/2015` is in B1.

Comment: Brilliant, never thought to use `Text` function to take care of the single digit week numbers.

Answer (score 0):

So not the most elegant of solutions, but a start I guess.

Assuming your data starts at B2 and goes down. Try this in A2 and drag down

```
=CONCATENATE(right(B2,4),If(WEEKNUM(B2,2)<10,CONCATENATE(0,WEEKNUM(B2,2)),WEEKNUM(B2,2))
```

This formula assumes your weekday starts on Monday. If your weekday starts on a different day, Change the 2 in the weeknum to whatever suits. 1 being sunday, 2 being monday, etc.

Lastly this formula doesn't even look at end date.